# ¿Cómo descargar varios ficheros en paralelo a través de SFTP (librería phpseclib3 de PHP)?

Tags: php, php7, hilos, sftp, phpseclib3

Tengo un proyecto de PHP que utiliza la librería phpseclib3 para conectarse por FTP/SFTP y descargarse ficheros, pero los descarga uno por uno.

Estoy leyendo la documentación y no encuentro ninguna opción para habilitar las descargas en paralelo.

Mi código es el siguiente:

```
public function downloadFile(string $remoteFile, string $localPath)
  {
    $localFile = $localPath.$remoteFile;
    $this->sftp->get($remoteFile, $localFile);
    return $this->checkCorrectFile($localFile);
  }

//Obtengo todos los "elementos" del directorio raíz 
foreach($elements as $element){
    if($sftp->isFile($element)){
        $sftp->downloadFile(remoteFile: $element, localPath: $localPath); 
    }
```

Comment: no se puede a menos que implementes la extension pthreads  que no es comun que este en los servidores.

Comment: Otra forma de hacerlo es ejecutar comandos del CLI desde el CGI, que no es muy comun y perderias el control para evaluar si realmente se descargaron o no los archivos...

Comment: cómo sería con pthreads? uno por directorio?

Comment: por archivo se crea un hilo para llamar a X funcion php que hace la descarga algo como: $thread = new Thread('downloadFileInParallel', [$sftp, $element, $localPath]); pero tienes que validar primero el funcionamiento de la extension y hacer la implementacion ...